# jQuery get complex multiple checked values from checkbox to array

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, checkbox

I want to dynamically display the content of a site in relation to choice of visitors when it selects checkbox. No problem for sends information in Ajax and the php side. But I can not create an array like I want in jQuery.

HTML :

```
<div id="filter">
    <div class="sizes">
        <input type="checkbox" data-group="size_catalog" data-value="32">
        <input type="checkbox" data-group="size_catalog" data-value="36">
        <input type="checkbox" data-group="size_catalog" data-value="38">
        <input type="checkbox" data-group="size_catalog" data-value="40">
    </div>
    <div class="colors">
        <input type="checkbox" data-group="color_catalog" data-value="red">
        <input type="checkbox" data-group="color_catalog" data-value="blue">
        <input type="checkbox" data-group="color_catalog" data-value="black">
    </div>
</div>
```

The object with multiple array I would like to have (it is necessary to group the same data-group) :

```
var myArray = {size_catalog : ["32", "36", "38"], color_catalog: [red, blue]};
```

My current code (found on the internet and adapted) that create a simple array:

```
    function getChecked(){
        var opts= [];
        $checkboxes.each(function(){
            if(this.checked){
                opts.push(this.value);
            }
        });
        return opts;
    }

    function updateSearch(opts){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "class.search.php",
            dataType : 'json',
            cache: false,
            data: {filterOpts: opts},
            success: function(records){
                ...
            }
        });
    }

    var $checkboxes = $("input:checkbox");
    $checkboxes.on("change", function(){
        var opts = getChecked();
        updateSearch(opts);
    });

    updateSearch();
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: FYI, `myArray` isn't an array but an object

Comment: `var array = []` should be `var opts = []`?

Comment: @Barmar Yes mishandling. I just corrected. thx

Comment: @A.Wolff I know there are no multidimensional array in javascript. It is for this reason that I put quotation marks. but you're right. I will correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do that by iterating and creating an object with the `size-catalog` as keys, and an array you push to as a value.

```
var $checkboxes = $("input:checkbox");

$checkboxes.on('change', function() {
    var obj = {};

    $checkboxes.filter(':checked').each(function() {
        var n = $(this).data('group'),
            v = $(this).data('value');

        n in obj ? obj[n].push( v ) : obj[n] = [v];
    });

    $.post('class.search.php', {filterOpts: obj}, 'json').done(function(records) {

    });

});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/ygsL7m2y/)

Comment: Thank you very much! This community is really powerful.

Comment: I try to convert $.post to $.ajax for adding beforeSend with loading gif but it does not work. Did I make a mistake?

   $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax-search.php",
    dataType : 'json',
    data: {filterOpts: obj},
    beforeSend: function(){
     $('#displaycloth').text('Chargement...');
    },
   })
   .done(function(records){
    $('#displaycloth').html(records)
   });

Answer (score 0):

Thats not a multidimentional array, thats an object containing 2 different arrays. If you want that, then something like this is what you want:

```
function getChecked() {
  var sizeArray = [];
  var colorArray = [];

  $checkboxes.each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      if ($(this).data('group') == 'size_catalog')
        sizeArray.push($(this).data('value'));
      else if ($(this).data('group') == 'color_catalog')
        colorArray.push($(this).data('value'));
    }
  });

  return {
    size_catalog: sizeArray,
    color_catalog: colorArray
  };
}
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/sjopme3r/)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer me.